# How to show first letter of last name in angular

Tags: angular

I want to show First and Last Name. Full First name and first letter of last name. For example, if the name is John Doe, then I need to show as John D.

Here is what I have done so far, but it is omitting letters from the last.

```
<div class="posted-details">
  <div><span class="bold small-title">Posted by</span> 
       <span class="user-name-holder">
          <a href="/users/f18b1630fdf8-p-26404332/" class="user-name" data-ui-test="user-name">
          {{ selectJobPostData.posted_by.first_name }} 
          {{ selectJobPostData.posted_by.last_name.slice(0, -4) }}.</a>
       </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: slice(0,1)? Or charAt(0)

Answer (score 0):

Thank to penleychan. It worked this way

```
slice(0,1)
```

Comment: You can use also `last_name[0]` -when we use an index in a string get's the character in this position-